# UICollectionViewCell Auto Layout Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass with programmatically. I am trying to create with auto layout support.

I want to a `UIView` to the content view of the cell with adding leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints. But When I do that, My `UIView's` width and height stays zero. Here is my code inside `initWithFrame` method:

```
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_someView];
    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-2-[someView]-2-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"someView" : _someView}];
    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-2-[someView]-2-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"someView" : _someView}];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
```

And here is the UI debugger's screenshot:
[image]

Why are these constraints are greyed out?

Thank you!

Comment: Are all your constraints installed in whatever size class you are using? Not sure about the visual debugger, but IB/Storyboards a greyed out constraint is one that exists in the project but is not installed in whatever size class combination the editor is showing (default is any/any)

Comment: Is your console throwing any layout warnings? Also setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskintoConstraints` to NO  on the contentView might break the cells layout system. Try not doing that.

Comment: @WarrenBurton it worked! Thank you!!!! Please respond as an answer and I will vote and approve it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `contentView` is owned by the `UICollectionViewCell` so the action of doing this

`self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

breaks the layout in the cell.

Its perfectly reasonable to do this for any subviews you own and add to the content view but messing with views you don't own runs the risk of breaking the layout.

Comment: I keep forgetting this every time I do a project without storyboard lol :)